# Node js. Cannot find module 'cache'

Tags: node.js, module

My index.js file requires module cache.
I have installed it using npm but the error doesnt go away.

```
var cache = require('cache')({
backend: 'memory'
});
```

After this didnt work i installed it using -g option as well but the error persisted.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Does `cache` exist in your `node_modules` directory? Did you run `npm install -d` in your root directory?

Comment: Tried that as well.same error in the same place
edit - cache exists in my node-modules directory as well.it doesnt get detected

Comment: What happens if you write require('./node_modules/cache')?

Comment: @jithujose - that doesnt help.

Comment: @Amberlamps - No issues.thanks for the help anyway. :)

Comment: @BlahBlah Please update the question with additional information (node version, npm version, platform, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**install the cache module** with this command.

```
npm i node-cache
```

Answer (score -2):

You can read this web page: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache)
There are many packages you need to install like cash module: `npm install -g npm-cache`

Comment: Please make your answer complete by itself, we shouldn't rely only on external content